# How to use the wiki UMAC example function?

Tags: integrity, umac

I want to use the  [wiki UMAC example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMAC) to protect the integrity of the communication between 2 devices. Unfortunately I am not quite sure of the meaning of the parameters and I don't want to get it wrong:

> The following C function generates a 24 bit UMAC. It assumes that secret is a multiple of 24 bits, msg is not longer than secret and
>   result already contains the 24 secret bits e.g. f(nonce). nonce does
>   not need to be contained in msg.

```
void UHash24 (uchar *msg, uchar *secret, int len, uchar *result)
```

- msg - my message
- secret I assume it is the secret Key (present on both devices) 16 byte key which I'll duplicate as many times as necessary to make it bigger than the msg length.
- len - the msg length
- result - here I don't understand what f(nonce) mean - I have a 4 byte nonce - I assume that I should make a function to convert it to 3 byte?

I have seen in another post that secret should be f(nonce, Key) - is this a good suggestion? (f could be Tea algorithm)

Can I use the same f function, get only 3 bytes and use it for the result parameter?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. But nonetheless you can edit your question into an attempt at learning the basics of message authentication codes.

Comment: I think the configuration parameters of a function are allowed here, even if they are - in the end - required for a C function. Now if there were issues *applying* the parameters or encoding the values then it becomes more of a programming question and it would be more at home at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DannyNiu I am interested in the logic/concepts of the algorithm itself; after having these I can use the function correctly.

Comment: @John Rastem  When it comes to the topic of UMAC, it is amazing how unclear the explanations tend to be. I too hope that someone will respond to this important question that lacks a clear answer elsewhere on the internet.